# Linked-Server stored procedure data missing in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS using Visual Studio 2010 Design view. I am using a stored procedure as my data set. When I run out the stored procedure in SQL Server, it runs fine. When I run it out in preview, I am missing some columns.

In the stored procedure, I join a table that lives on a linked-server through a synonym. These seem to be the missing columns in the preview.

Is there a known issue where linked-server data will not get returned in SSRS even if it compiles in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to permissions if you have the linked server set to execute as the context of the current user - it will use the credentials of the **Data Source** in SSRS.

Is your data source configured to use a specific user? Try running the sproc as that user?

-- Edit based on Comments --

It appears the issue is probably with the linked server authentication. There are a few ways round this;

- Set up Kerberos pass-through authentication so you can tick 'Be made using the login's current security context' in the linked server properties
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2008/01/02/how-to-set-up-a-kerberos-authentication-scenario-with-sql-server-linked-servers/
  https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3696506/Setting-Up-Delegation-for-Linked-Servers.htm
- Use a SQL (not Windows) account on the remote server by ticking 'Be made using this security context' and entering the sql accounts details
- Use a scheduled job of some kind to transfer the data the sproc returns over to one server so that linked server connection is not required
- Change the report to query both data servers separately (as two different data sources and data sets), then join the results within the report (this is a bit fiddley and not really recommended)

Comment: I have "Use Windows Authentication (integrated security)" selected as my primary data source's credentials in SSRS. I have been able to run out queries on both servers/databases as independent Shared Data Sources before.

Comment: If you open the linked server properties (From the server the data source points to), is it set to use the current context? Or a specific account?

Comment: is this the same as going to the server/database that i am attempting to link in and doing SELECT CURRENT_USER; GO? If so, it is my specific profile on our companies larger network

Comment: No - If you expland the Server Objects node in the object explorer (in SSMS, connected to the first server), then select Linked Servers, then right click and properties the one you are trying to connect too, then select the security tab - you will see the security options for linked servers differ from standard connections. This is because of Kerberos being needed for two hop connections, so sometimes people set linked servers up with a fixed account, which may be your issue

Comment: This link runs through the options: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: sorry a bit new to this... but i got to the linked server properties. Under Local Server Login to Remove Server Login Mappings it is blank. The "For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:" then Not Be Made is selected. Maybe thats the issue

Comment: That is indeed probably the issue - You can tick 'Be made using the login's current security context', however to do this you will need to setup Kerberos properly, which is a bit of hassle. The alternative is to tick 'Be made using this security context', however that only works with SQL accounts (not windows accounts) which is bad practice these days... Sadly there isn't an easy way round this... The 'easy' way is to run a job that moves the data from the proc over to the one server to report off (usually in a data warehouse?)